PowerShell Execution with RunOnce fails
I want to set the old context menu for all new user in Windows 11. The solution for the current user is to set the following reg-key:
HKCU:\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32
Then the explorer has to restart.
With this reg-file I place a powershell command in the RunOnce section:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]
"OldContextMenu"="powershell -Command \"$regpath=\"HKCU:\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\\InprocServer32\" ; if(-not (Test-Path $regpath)){New-Item -Path $regpath -Force} ; Set-Item -Path $regpath -Value \"\" ; $null=Read-Host ; Stop-Process -Processname Explorer -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -force\""

The resulting PowerShell commands run well in a PowerShell window with or without admin rights:
$regpath="HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32" ; if(-not (Test-Path $regpath)){New-Item -Path $regpath -Force} ; Set-Item -Path $regpath -Value "" ; $null=Read-Host ; Stop-Process -Processname Explorer -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -force

Howto get this work in the RunOnce section?
I see the PowerShell window open at the beginning of the logon, but the code is not successful.
Tried to place an input line in the code for debugging purposes.

Do you make sure "RunOnce" is executed in PowerShell?

@stackprotector Yes, I have another Command in the RunOnce section, which is similar to this failing command and it as also a PowerShell command: powershell -Command "Remove-Item "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband" -Recurse -Force; Stop-Process -Processname Explorer -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -force" This command removes the unwanted Edge and Store App out of the taskbar.

Change the command to start some script file, and add debugging logic to it, to check what happens...
